# How can I open amp login in the same frame in which it was clicked (not pop window)?

Tags: amp-html

I want to open the subscribe page in the same window, as opposed to having the subscribe page open in a pop-up window. Is that possible?

Right now I have it as:

```
    <div class="subscribe_button" on="tap:amp-access.login-subscribe" role="button" tabindex="0">
            Subscribe
    </div>
```